# WTSQueryUserToken Fails, getlasterror() returns 1723

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, rpc

I have a windows service that is running under the credentials of the system account. The service periodically polls windows for the active console session id, i.e. the interactive logged in windows user, and then retrieves the user token associated with the active console session id by pinvoking the wtsapi32.dll function WTSQueryUserToken(…). This implementation works flawlessly 99.9% percent of the time in the field. Lately however, I have found a customer where this implementation periodically (but never consistently) fails to retrieve the user token of the active console session id.

See customer's os info at the bottom of this post.

When WTSQueryUserToken() fails, GetLastError() returns the Windows System error code 1723.

The description of error code 1723: “The RPC server is too busy to complete this operation”

Here is example code snippet demonstrating the implementation:

```
int ActiveSession = 0;
Win32Wrapper.GetActiveConsoleSessionId(ref ActiveSession);
IntPtr UserToken = IntPtr.Zero;

if(!Win32Wrapper.WTSQueryUserToken(ActiveSession, ref UserToken))
{
   int myErr = Convert.ToInt32(Win32Wrapper.GetLastError());
   log("Failed to retrieve UserToken." + myErr.ToString());
   return;
}
else
{
   log("Retrieved User Token");
}
```

Does anyone know what might be the culprit ?

Here’s the customer’s setup:

- Authentication: Active Directory
- Operating System:
- Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600 Service
- Pack 3 Current UI Culture:     en-US
- Current Culture:     en-US CLR
- Version:         2.0.50727.3603
- IE Version:         8.0.6001.18702
- System type:         32 bit Free
- Physical Memory:     411MB Total
- Physical Memory:     893MB System
- Manufacturer:     Dell Inc.
- Model:   Vostro   1000
- Processor 1:   AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual-Core Processor TK-57

Services:

Name:     Alerter
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Application Layer Gateway Service
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Running
Name:     Apple Mobile Device
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Application Management
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     ASP.NET State Service
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Ati HotKey Poller
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Windows Audio
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Background Intelligent Transfer Service
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Bonjour Service
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Computer Browser
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Indexing Service
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     ClipBook
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     .NET Runtime Optimization Service v2.0.50727_X86
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     COM+ System Application
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Cryptographic Services
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     DCOM Server Process Launcher
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     DHCP Client
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Logical Disk Manager Administrative Service
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Logical Disk Manager
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     DNS Client
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Wired AutoConfig
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Extensible Authentication Protocol Service
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Error Reporting Service
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Event Log
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     COM+ Event System
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Running
Name:     Fast User Switching Compatibility
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     FlipShare Service
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Windows Presentation Foundation Font Cache 3.0.0.0
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Help and Support
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     HID Input Service
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Health Key and Certificate Management Service
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     HTTP SSL
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     InstallDriver Table Manager
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Windows CardSpace
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     IMAPI CD-Burning COM Service
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     iPod Service
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Java Quick Starter
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Server
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Workstation
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     McAfee Framework Service
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     McAfee McShield
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     McAfee Task Manager
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Machine Debug Manager
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Messenger
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Vision Control Manager
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     NetMeeting Remote Desktop Sharing
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Distributed Transaction Coordinator
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Windows Installer
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Network Access Protection Agent
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Network DDE
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Network DDE DSDM
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Net Logon
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Network Connections
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Running
Name:     Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Network Location Awareness (NLA)
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Running
Name:     NLCS Agent
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     NT LM Security Support Provider
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Removable Storage
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Microsoft Office Diagnostics Service
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Office Source Engine
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Plug and Play
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Pml Driver HPZ12
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Stopped
Name:     IPSEC Services
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Protected Storage
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Remote Access Connection Manager
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Remote Desktop Help Session Manager
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Routing and Remote Access
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Remote Registry
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     QoS RSVP
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Security Accounts Manager
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Smart Card
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Task Scheduler
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Secondary Logon
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     System Event Notification
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Windows Firewall/Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Shell Hardware Detection
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Print Spooler
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     System Restore Service
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Stopped
Name:     SSDP Discovery Service
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Running
Name:     Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     MS Software Shadow Copy Provider
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     System Interface Service
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Performance Logs and Alerts
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Telephony
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Terminal Services
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Running
Name:     Themes
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Telnet
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Distributed Link Tracking Client
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Universal Plug and Play Device Host
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Uninterruptible Power Supply
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Volume Shadow Copy
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Windows Time
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     WebClient
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Windows Defender
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Windows Management Instrumentation
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Dell Wireless WLAN Tray Service
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Portable Media Serial Number Service
     Start Mode:     Disabled
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Windows Management Instrumentation Driver Extensions
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     WMI Performance Adapter
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Security Center
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Windows Search
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Automatic Updates
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Running
Name:     Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Wireless Zero Configuration
     Start Mode:     Auto
     State:     Stopped
Name:     Network Provisioning Service
     Start Mode:     Manual
     State:     Stopped

Processes:

Name:     System Idle Process
     Working Set:    28KB
Name:     System
     Working Set:    244KB
Name:     smss.exe
     Working Set:    428KB
Name:     csrss.exe
     Working Set:    3984KB
Name:     winlogon.exe
     Working Set:    3944KB
Name:     services.exe
     Working Set:    3612KB
Name:     lsass.exe
     Working Set:    5344KB
Name:     ati2evxx.exe
     Working Set:    3036KB
Name:     svchost.exe
     Working Set:    5076KB
Name:     svchost.exe
     Working Set:    5384KB
Name:     MsMpEng.exe
     Working Set:    39384KB
Name:     svchost.exe
     Working Set:    23792KB
Name:     svchost.exe
     Working Set:    4280KB
Name:     svchost.exe
     Working Set:    4944KB
Name:     WLTRYSVC.EXE
     Working Set:    1652KB
Name:     BCMWLTRY.EXE
     Working Set:    9820KB
Name:     spoolsv.exe
     Working Set:    8364KB
Name:     svchost.exe
     Working Set:    5356KB
Name:     AppleMobileDeviceService.exe
     Working Set:    4284KB
Name:     mDNSResponder.exe
     Working Set:    4368KB
Name:     FlipShareService.exe
     Working Set:    5316KB
Name:     FrameworkService.exe
     Working Set:    6048KB
Name:     mcshield.exe
     Working Set:    55800KB
Name:     vstskmgr.exe
     Working Set:    564KB
Name:     mdm.exe
     Working Set:    2748KB
Name:     csagtprosvc.exe
     Working Set:    5644KB
Name:     naPrdMgr.exe
     Working Set:    2044KB
Name:     svchost.exe
     Working Set:    4308KB
Name:     searchindexer.exe
     Working Set:    20460KB
Name:     svchost.exe
     Working Set:    21864KB
Name:     unsecapp.exe
     Working Set:    3828KB
Name:     alg.exe
     Working Set:    4336KB
Name:     wmiprvse.exe
     Working Set:    7576KB
Name:     ati2evxx.exe
     Working Set:    3600KB
Name:     explorer.exe
     Working Set:    33096KB
Name:     SynTPEnh.exe
     Working Set:    4736KB
Name:     WLTRAY.EXE
     Working Set:    6644KB
Name:     MSASCui.exe
     Working Set:    7824KB
Name:     shstat.exe
     Working Set:    820KB
Name:     UdaterUI.exe
     Working Set:    2304KB
Name:     stsystra.exe
     Working Set:    8100KB
Name:     Mctray.exe
     Working Set:    2396KB
Name:     ctfmon.exe
     Working Set:    3252KB
Name:     DyKnowLogSender.exe
     Working Set:    23972KB

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once. So I advise to repeat this call some time later (using Sleep). If it works 99% then it is likely that it will work after trying several more times. I also would add a counter so there is no infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is Win32Wrapper.GetLastError actually calling GetLastError? That function can't be reliably called from managed code. Instead, you should add SetLastError=true to the DllImport attribute of all functions that sets the error (WTSQueryUserToken in your case), and then check the result with Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().

Comment: Thanks Mattias, my DLLImport statement did not set the attribute. I will incorporate your suggestion in a sample program to see if Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() returns a different error code.